# Glow in Aforge.net

Tags: c#, aforge, glow

How can I make a glow effect in Aforge. I have blobs on black background and I would like to surround them with a glow.

tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a rectangle over them and use WPF Blur effect.
Read about it here: (Scroll to bottom)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.outerglowbitmapeffect.aspx
[image: Example]